# How many times the copy ctor is called in the following?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

In the book I read this question, the answer was **8 times**.

- How?
- *Please explain me.* :)

---

```
Temp fun1(Temp x)
{
Temp y(x);
Temp z=y;
return z;
}
void main()
{
Temp a;
Temp b=fun1(a);
Temp c=fun1(b);
}
```

Comment: Did the book not explain it? (It's worth noting here that the book is wrong.)

Comment: It probably doesn't mention RVO (Return Value Optimization) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: Also if the book is recommending the main function to return `void` it has faults.

Comment: The question itself is wrong, completely wrong, unless it is a trick question.  No one can predict how many times the copy constructor is called.  **Get another book**.  The correct answer is -- "we don't know" or "undetermined", not `8`.

Comment: Why don't you try that out yourself. The result mentioned in the book cold come from side effects (like a `cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;` call in the copy constructor).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no [MCVE] provided. The code shown [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cfcd87ea61077e8).

Comment: Copying can be elided so it's not really possible to tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
class Temp
{
public:
    int a;
    Temp() : a(0) {}
    Temp(const Temp &ref) : a(ref.a)
    {
      std::cout << "Temp(Temp&)" << std::endl;
    }
};

Temp fun1(Temp x)
{
Temp y(x);
Temp z=y;
return z;
}
int main(int ac, char**av)
{
Temp a;
Temp b=fun1(a);
Temp c=fun1(b);
}
```

Shows 6 calls for clang.

```
786_ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
787_ ./a.out
Temp(Temp&)
Temp(Temp&)
Temp(Temp&)
Temp(Temp&)
Temp(Temp&)
Temp(Temp&)
```

Comment: thanks, in the book, they have just given the answer without any explanation.